# laravel post 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

## Route web.php

```
    Route::get('admin/exam_categry', 'Admin@exam_category');
    Route::post('admin/add_new_category', 'Admin@add_new_category');
```

## controller Admin.php here its all code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Oex_category;
use Validator;
class Admin extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function exam_category(){
        return view('admin.exam_category');
    }
    public function add_new_category(Request $request){
       $validator=validator::make($request->all(),['name'=>'required']);
       if($validator->passes())
       {
           $cat = new Oex_category();
           $cat->name=$request->name;
           $cat->status=1;
           $cat->save();
           $arr=array('status'=>'true','message'=>'success','reload'=>url('admin/exam_categry'));
       }
       else
           {
           $arr=array('status'=>'false','message'=>$validator->errors()->all());
       }
       echo jason_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

## Form exam_category where we enter data

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Dashboard')
@section('content')
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Category</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Category</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <!-- Default box -->
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Title</h3>

                                <div class="card-tools">
                                 <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="javascript:;"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                               <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                                   <thead>
                                   <th>#</th>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                                   <th>Status</th>
                                   <th>Action</th>
                                   </thead>
                                   <tbody>

                                   </tbody>
                                   <tfoot>
                                   <th>#</th>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                                   <th>Status</th>
                                   <th>Action</th>
                                   </tfoot>
                               </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-body -->

                            <!-- /.card-footer-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Category</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{url('admin/add_new_category')}}"  class="database_operation" >
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Enter Category Name</label>
                                   {{csrf_field()}}
                                   <input type="text"  required="required" name="name" placeholder="Enter Category Name" class="form-control">
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

## custom.js file

```
$(document).on('submit','.database_operation',function(){
    var url=$(this).attr('action');
    var data=$(this).serialize();
    $.post(url,data,function(fb){
       var resp = $.parseJSON(fb);
       consol.log(resp);
    })
    return false;
});
```

## exam_category Model when i add category then i show error when i inspect element

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Oex_category extends Model
{
    protected $table="oex_categories";
    protected $primaryKey="id";
    protected $fillable=['name','status'];
}
```

## storage/logs

```
 [2020-06-11 23:37:28] local.ERROR: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\jason_encode() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\jason_encode() at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin.php:31)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin->add_new_category(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('add_new_categor...', Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin), 'add_new_categor...')
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(68): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\online_exam_sys\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#52 {main}
"}
```

## error message am waste 2 days to solve it but its not working

first am face 405 error but now 500 server error plz if any one know help me.....
    jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/add_new_category 500 (Internal Server Error)
    send @ jquery.min.js:2
    ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
    k. @ jquery.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ custom.js:6
    dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
    v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2 show when i inspect page

Comment: Post your server logs that have the actual php error.

Comment: where the location of server logs am new laravel user am know little bit...

Comment: the error log literally tells you where the problem is and what function call is causing the error ... and the line number

Answer (score 2):

Your controller Admin is returning with a typo:

```
echo jason_encode($arr);
```

The correct sintax is:

`echo json_encode($arr);`

But the real problem here is that your server is not returning the errors. Make sure your .env file is:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

And than look for errors on:

> \storage\logs

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MMPbJYrPmammNykkLxeWZrGaS8WehLlNmF6cAB7IKN0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MMPbJYrPmammNykkLxeWZrGaS8WehLlNmF6cAB7IKN0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: Well, it's like I've said on my answer, jason_encode is not a valid function. Learn to read the erros log files, it's mandatory if you want to be a programmer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the right code you should use.

Comment: It's the first answer here on this page. Go to your Admin Controller (Admin.php) and change "jason_encode" to "json_encode".

Comment: custom.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: consol is not defined
    at Object.success (custom.js:8)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)                                                                                                                               
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2) new error show

Comment: Now your error is in your custom.js, line 8: change "consol" to "console". We are going to stay here all day. Look online for trainning, "How to read stack error on Laravel" and "How to read javascript error log". Good luck and keep learning.

Comment: thanks alot sir i solved problem ...and sir you are so coprative...

Comment: Keep learning and you will go far. Help other people here to learn even more.

Comment: sir i face another problem?

Comment: Sir plz visit my profile where is my second question am face another error 